# Appcelerator push notification internationalization

Tags: push-notification, internationalization, translation, appcelerator, appcelerator-arrow

I deployed a few apps which are used in several countries.
Now I'd like to send notifications but I can't found a way to send notifications in different languages.
My need is to send some news to the users, so it's not convainant for me to integrate translation into the i18n files.

I suppose i'm not the first to have this kind of question but I didn't found a lot of help on internet.

Please don't hesitate to share some tips or good practice about that

Thanks in advance,

Arnaud

Answer (score 0):

APN and GCM themselves are only aware of the token for each device. It's Push Service Providers like Arrow Push that keep track of meta information on each token.

For Arrow Push you could create a separate channel for each language. Then when you send out a push notification you will need to do so for each language separately and target the related channel.

To subscribe a token/user to a channel see:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Cloud.PushNotifications-method-subscribeToken

To send to all tokens/users in a channel see:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/arrowdb/latest/#!/api/PushNotifications-method-notify

Or send via the Appcelerator Platform Dashboard.

Comment: So there is no way to send a notification to all devices that are in a specific counrty ?

Comment: Not out of the box as Google and Apple provide the service. You will need to take care of grouping device tokens yourself.